# What is the difference for the convergence? What is correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a Lebesgue integrable function, $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I would like to approximate it by nice functions for instance $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}\subset C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ smooth compactly supported functions.

What convergence should I use of these two?
$$f_n \rightarrow f \mbox{ in } L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$$
as $n\to \infty$? Or rather require that $\sup_{n\geq 1} \|f_n\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}<\infty$ and
$$f_n \rightarrow f$$
a.e. in $x$?

What is the main difference? Does one imply the other?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "require that $\sup_{n\geq 1}\|f_n\|$" ? Require that this Supremum exists? And what does "a.e. for every x" mean? Is it "almost everywhere" or "for every x" ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the "less infinity". Yes it simply means almost everywhere in $x$.

Comment: Convergence in $L^1$ implies the existence of a subsequence of $(f_{n_j})_{j\in\mathbb N}$ of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $f_{n_j} \to f$ a.e.

On the other hand, $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere implies $L^1$ convergence if there exists $g\in L^1$ with $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ for almost every $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. The second condition you mention does **not** imply $L^1$ convergence.

As a counterexample take $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $f\equiv 0$. Then define 
$$f_n(x):=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$$

Then clearly $f_n\to f$ a.e. and $\sup_{n\geq 1} \|f_n\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}<\infty$, but you don't have $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: Fantastic example! As I expected :) Thanks!